# include C++ application in firebreath

Tags: visual-c++, firebreath, pjsip

I have created a C++ application using Pjsip Stack and my next step to create a plug-in,for which i am using firebreath. Being a newbee, I dont have any idea of including my C++ project in Firebreath application. Although I searched many links for over a week and tried stuff on my own, I couldnt come up with solution to my problem.
If I can get any guidance for the same I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to learn how to write a firebreath plugin, which you can do by going to http://firebreath.org and following the tutorials.  You need to keep a few things in mind, though:

1. Plugins have a different lifecycle than applications.

   - They start when the browser says and have to go away when the browser says and they can't block the main thread.
2. They run in a process that they don't own.

   - Global variables are shared between all instances of the plugin
   - There could be any number of said instances
   - Things like the current working directory should probably be left alone.

Turning an application into a plugin is more a process of porting than it is of embedding, and how hard it is depends on how well the application is written; remember that your plugin could be instantiated and destroyed many times before the process is unloaded, so if you have memory leaks it can be a major problem.

The main thing, though, as I said earlier, is just to learn how to write a firebreath plugin.  You can best start that by looking at the examples in the repo (particularly fbtestplugin) and following the tutorial to create a new project, then just play until you figure it out.  There is an [IRC chat room](http://npapi.com/chat) and a [google group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/firebreath-dev) where you can get help.